# match table row id's with a common prefix

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

This might be merely a syntax question.

I am unclear how to match only table rows whose id begins with rowId_

```
agent = Mechanize.new
  pageC1 = agent.get("/customStrategyScreener!list.action")
```

The table has class=tableCellDT.

```
 pageC1.search('table.tableCellDT tr[@id=rowId_]')  # parses OK but returns 0 rows since rowId_ is not matched exactly.

 pageC1.search('table.tableCellDT tr[@id=rowId_*]')  # Throws an error since * is not treated like a wildcard string match
```

EXAMPLE HTML:

```
 <table id="row" cellpadding="5" class="tableCellDT" cellspacing="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="tableHeaderDT">#</th>
<th class="tableHeaderDT sortable">
<a href="?d-16544-s=1&amp;d-16544-o=2&amp;d-16544-p=1">Screener</a></th>
<th class="tableHeaderDT sortable">
<a href="?d-16544-s=2&amp;d-16544-o=2&amp;d-16544-p=1">Strategy</a></th>
<th class="tableHeaderDT"> </th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="rowId_BullPut" class="odd">
<td>   1  </td>
<td>   Bull</td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="link1?model.itemId=2262">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="javascript:deleteScreener('link2?model.itemId=2262');">Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="link3?model.itemId=2262&amp;amp;model.source=list">View</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td></tr>
```

NOTE

**pageC1** is a `Mechanize::Page` object, not a `Nokogiri` anything. Sorry that wasn't clear at first.
Mechanize::Page doesn't have #css or #xpath methods, but a Nokogiri doc can be extracted from it (used internally anyway).

Comment: What do you want to extract?

Comment: There will be other rows whose id's are NOT ="rowId_xxxx". Those I need to ignore.  Eg. ignore `<tr id="otherPrefix_Credit" class="odd">`

Comment: I understand that, but want to know what output you want given your input.

Comment: Though not in the question, ultimately, for each rowId_* tr I need to extract the suffix after rowId_ in the tr's id, text of cell 2, and 3rd link target of cell 4 (where text="View").

Comment: An array of Nokogiri rows is fine, like what `pageC1.search('table.tableCellDT tr')` returns, or an array of arrays (each element containing a string of those three things)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `tr` elements that have an `id` starting with "rowId_":

```
pageC1.search('//tr[starts-with(@id, "rowId_")]')
```

Comment: `pageC1.search('tr[starts-with(@id, "rowId")]')`  gets me `Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Invalid number of arguments: //tr[starts-with(., @id, "rowId")]   from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:159:in `evaluate' `

Comment: I am checking `starts-with` and `contains` at http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp ; know of a better reference more pertinent to Ruby/Mechanize/Nokogiri?

Comment: Strange that it is modifying your `starts-with()` to include a "`.`" as the first argument. Try specifically using the `xpath()` method. If that doesn't work, try `'tr[id[starts-with(.,"rowId_")]]'`.

Comment: I believe the problem is that by using `search` Nokogiri doesn't know if you are using CSS or XPath, and it's converting your XPath query as though it were CSS.

Comment: Seems like I now need to extract a Nokogiri doc from a Mechanize Page object. `pageC1.xpath('tr[starts-with(@id, "rowId_")]')` gets me `NoMethodError: undefined method `xpath' for #<Mechanize::Page:0xa0c2790>`

Comment: @Marcos Why not just use the easier CSS syntax from my answer? Note that you are STILL mixing CSS and XPath syntax in your string there, which won't work.

Comment: Also tried `pageC1.search('tr[id[starts-with(.,"rowId_")]]')` which errors `Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '[' after '#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0xb28ca48>'`but thanks for the right direction

Comment: Use the updated XPath in my comment. You have to start with `//` and Mechanize/Nokogiri will recognize it as XPath.

Comment: @MarkThomas Thanks, that did the trick. Even though it's not limited to tables having class "tableCellDT" only--tried adding a few things to the xpath unsuccessfully--but I can deal with that if it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want either the CSS3 [attribute starts-with selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```
pageC1.css('table.tableCellDT tr[id^="rowId_"]')
```

or the XPath [`starts-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) function:

```
pageC1.xpath('.//table[@class="tableCellDT"]//tr[starts-with(@id,"rowId_")]')
```

Although the Nokogiri [`Node#search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search) method will intelligently pick between CSS or XPath selector syntax based on what you wrote, that does not mean that you can mix both CSS and XPath selector syntax in the same query.

In action:

```
>> require 'nokogiri'
#=> true

>> doc = Nokogiri.HTML <<ENDHTML; true #hide output from IRB
">> <table class="foo"><tr id="rowId_nonono"><td>Nope</td></tr></table>
">> <table class="tableCellDT">
">>   <tr id="rowId_yesyes"><td>Yes1</td></tr>
">>   <tr id="rowId_andme2"><td>Yes2</td></tr>
">>   <tr id="rowIdNONONO"><td>Needs underscore</td></tr>
">> </table>
">> ENDHTML
#=> true

>> doc.css('table.tableCellDT tr[id^="rowId_"]').map(&:text)
#=> ["Yes1", "Yes2"]

>> doc.xpath('.//table[@class="tableCellDT"]//tr[starts-with(@id,"rowId_")]').map(&:text)
#=> ["Yes1", "Yes2"]
```

Comment: I like the CSS approach better, but: `NoMethodError: undefined method `css' for #<Mechanize::Page:0xa0c2790>`

Comment: @Marcos I'm sorry, I didn't see that you were using Mechanize. Just use `#search` along with CSS syntax.

Comment: Thanks for helping point in the right direction! I will try to inline the pageC1 object I have into the Nokogiri::Doc  that is needed to use #css and #xpath methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 
http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css

and the answers above, here is the final code that solves my problem of getting just the rows I need, and then reading only certain information from each one:

```
 pageC1.search('//tr[starts-with(@id, "rowId_")]').each do |row|

# Read the string after _ in rowId_, part of the "id" in <tr>
    rid = row.attribute("id").text.split("_")[1] # => "BullPut"

# Get the URL of the 3rd <a> link in <td> cell 4    
    link = row.css("td[4] a[3]")[0].attributes["href"].text # => "link3?model.itemId=2262&amp;amp;model.source=list"
 end
```